# PHP MVC: поиск по заголовкам

Tags: php, mvc, sqlite3, search

товарищи

Не получается организовать поиск по заголовкам постов. Вот код модели:

```
public function postSearch($posts) : array
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content, dateAdded, dateModified FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :termin";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    return $req->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Post::class);
}
```

Вот код контроллера:

```
public function search(HTTPRequest $req): void
{
    $termin = $_POST['termin'];
    $posts = $this->postManager->postSearch([
        'termin' => "%$termin%"
    ]);
    $this->show('../App/View/search.php', compact('termin', 'posts'));
}
```

Т. е. нужно чтобы после ввода в форму заголовка, выводилась превьюха статьи (это уже в виде). Массив $posts — пустой. Если в запросе вместо маски %termin% указывать конкретный заголовок, то всё выводится. Выходит, контроллер не понимает маску?

Comment: А где binding :termin параметра в prepared statement в функции postSearch? Вы не используете там переменную $posts, которая и содержит в себе значение из формы, по которому нужно искать.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, так `$req->bindValue(':termin', $posts, \PDO::PARAM_INT);` тоже не работает (

Comment: Сами догадаетесь [почему](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)?

Comment: Да, в инт преобразовывать самое то.

Comment: Ну да, в инт это я зря. А как сделать, подскажите пожалуйста! termin это же строка, а posts — массив. Что-то я совсем заплутал…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function postSearch($termin) : array
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content, dateAdded, dateModified FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :termin";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute(['termin' => $termin]);
    return $req->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Post::class);
}
```

Так как в контроллере в `postSearch` передается массив, то тогда правильней так:

```
public function postSearch($termin) : array
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content, dateAdded, dateModified FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :termin";
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute($termin);
    return $req->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Post::class);
}
```

Comment: Выводит предупреждение: `Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/linne/www/blattodea.org/App/Model/PostManager.php on line 52.` А вот вардамп-ы: `termin: string(21) "Elliptorhina javanica"` `posts: array(0) { }`

Comment: А, так как массив передаешь в функцию, то так  `$req->execute($termin);`

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! Всё работает «на ура»!